# Is this informal solution to the Monthy Hall problem wrong? And why?

Tags: probability, monty-hall

I recently opened my high school book about probability and statistics and I found an informal solution to the Monthy Hall problem. I translate it here:

*"Let's suppose that the first door chosen by the player is wrong and hides a goat. The host doesn't have any choice and opens the door with the other goat. In this case if the player changes door, he wins. If, instead, the first door chosen by the player is the right one, and the player changes door he loses.*

*So we can conclude that if the player changes door he wins if and only if his first choice was the wrong one, and this event has probability 2/3."*

This informal solution seems very convincing to me, but in my (flawed?) understanding I could apply it even if the presenter didn't know what there is behind the doors (while if I try to give a formal solution to the problem, at least using probability samples, this information changes the result).

Here the same solution modified:

*"Let's suppose that the first door chosen by the player is wrong and hides a goat. The host opens the door with the other goat by pure chance. In this case if the player changes door, he wins. If, instead, the first door chosen by the player is the right one, and the player changes door he loses.*

*So we can conclude that if the player changes door he wins if and only if his first choice was the wrong one, and this event has probability 2/3."*

My intuition here tells me that the fact that the host chooses a goat by chance doesn't change my initial probability of choosing a goat, that is still 2/3.

So there are two possibilities:

1) I can't see why the informal solution the book gave can't be applied anymore if the presenter doesn't know what there is behind the doors. In this case I ask: Why can't I apply that solution anymore?

2) The informal solution the book gave is wrong. In this case I ask: Why is it wrong?

I don't know much about probability theory: just the definition of a probability space and what conditional probability is.

Comment: This solution doesn't account for the case that the host might open the winning door.  This happens 1/3 of the time and cuts into the players chances of winning.

Comment: I know that my solution probably doesn't make any sense, but I'm still unsure. I clarified why in the comment under Especially Lime's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the actual Monty Hall problem, before we open any doors, a player can win by switching if and only if his initial choice was wrong, and this has probability $\frac 23$. He can win by not switching if and only if his original choice was right; this has probability $\frac13$. So it is clearly better to switch.

In the modified version where the host doesn't know which door is which, a player can win by switching if and only if **neither** the door he originally chose **nor** the door the host opens contains the prize. This has probability $\frac 23\times \frac 12=\frac13$. He can win by not switching if and only if his original choice was right; this still has probability $\frac13$. So both choices have an equal chance.

Comment: I'm still unsure if I understand: let's say the host already opened the door, and you see there is a goat behind it, then the only probability you must consider is the one that you picked a goat initally, since you know as a certainty that the host picked a goat: $ \frac {2}{3} * 1 =   \frac {2}{3} $

Comment: But when you say "let's say the host already opened the door," right there you're inserting an extra, highly nontrivial condition into the discussion. That sentence is where the logical mistake is made.

Comment: Here's an example of the type of error you're committing: "Roll a die; let's say it lands on a 5. What is the probability that the die is odd?" That's a valid (and uninteresting) question, but it is *not* the same as just asking about the probability that a die will be odd.

Comment: @emanueleascani if the host opens a random door and finds a goat, that information changes the probability that you picked the right door in the first place.

Comment: Initially, there are six possibilities for your door and the host's door: (C,G1), (C,G2), (G1, C), (G1, G2), (G2,C), (G2, G1). In two of those you picked the car, so your probability is $1/3$. But once you know that the host's door has a goat, there are only four possibilities left, and two of them you picked a car, so your probability is now $1/2$.

Comment: Ok, this checks out for me. But then why can't you repeat this same argument for the original Monty Hall? 

In the original Monty Hall the possibilities are: (C,G1), (C,G2), (G1, G2), (G2, G1) (I left out the two in which the host picks a car).

Then the host opens a door, but the possibilities this time remain the same: still four. But then I have chance of winning $1/2$ no matter if I keep my door or if I change it.

Comment: Because in the original Monty Hall the probabilities of those options aren't all the same. $P(G_1,G_2)=1/3$, because whenever you choose $G_1$ the host must choose $G_2$.

Answer (score 1):

You picked a door, and Monty opened another to reveal a goat, and now you need to evaluate the probability that the car is behind the remaining door (so you win if you switch).

There will certainly be a car behind the remaining door if you picked a goat given that Monty did so too.  This is true whether Monty cheated or was fair.

However, what *is* the probability that *you* picked a goat when *given* that Monty picked a goat?

- When Monty Cheats he always picks a goat.   If you picked a goat, he doesn't have any choice but to pick the other; if you picked a car he could pick either goat.

$$\mathsf P_{\small \!C}(Y\mid M)=\dfrac{\mathsf P_{\small \!C}(Y\cap M)}{\mathsf P_{\small \!C}(Y\cap M)+\mathsf P_{\small \!C}(Y^\complement\cap M)}=\dfrac{\tfrac 23\tfrac 11}{\tfrac 23\tfrac 11+\tfrac 13\tfrac 22}=\dfrac 23$$

- When Monty is fair, there was a chance he could've picked the car.   If you picked a goat, one from the two doors he could've picked had a goat; if you picked a car he could only pick either goat.

$$\mathsf P_{\small \!F}(Y\mid M)=\dfrac{\mathsf P_{\small \!F}(Y\cap M)}{\mathsf P_{\small \!F}(Y\cap M)+\mathsf P_{\small \!F}(Y^\complement\cap M)}=\dfrac {\tfrac 23\tfrac 12}{\tfrac 23\tfrac 12+\tfrac 13\tfrac 22}=\dfrac 12$$